# What's the most acurate running app?

Tags: running, app

I'm currently using Runkeeper to track my runs, but I'm not happy with the acuracy it provides. Even when I run in a perfectly straight line, the recorded track has quite a few deviations. I also found the current pace to vary massively, although I keep a steady pace.

Is there an app that is more acurate than a pure GPS tracker, e.g. by using map data to correct the GPS position to the closest road/trail or reading the accelerometer and compass to determine that I'm running in a straight line?

Answer (score 1):

I have used most of the GPS tracking apps on iPhone. Below is my rundown -

1. Walkmeter - This one is very satisfactory as far as accuracy is concerned. And it is very flexible for creating routes, workout types, screens, graphs etc. Its only drawbacks are that it is limited to iPhone, doesn't save workouts to some online website (backs up on iCloud) and some of its versions are not free. I still use it but then I have to upload the workouts to strava or something so that I don't lose the history if the phone stops working.
2. Runkeeper - It's great for presentation but its GPS readings are really bad. I never use it for any serious workouts because it loses GPS signal too often.
3. MapMyRun - It's reasonably accurate for walking but I never used it for running. Many of my friends use it and it works well enough. I don't like the interface (too busy, too many ads etc) much.
4. Strava - Works great for cycling. I never used it for walking/running but I see no reason it shouldn't work for those activities as well. It is on par with Walkmeter more or less. It is very popular, I like it.
5. GarminConnect/Nike/MovesCount - Too proprietary unless you own their watches/devices as well.

I used walkmeter for a long time but then I switched to using Garmin FR15 for casual / training runs/walks and Suunto's Ambit2 for serious stuff.  When I don't have any watches with me, I still use Walkmeter.